# What could the reason of the exception 'org.hibernate.QueryException Message Not all named parameters have been set:' possibly be?

Tags: java, hibernate, grails

So I am trying to execute the following query in grails

```
User user = springSecurityService.currentUser
def approverGroupList = approverGroupService.getApproverGroupsByUser(user.id)
return VerificationRequest.executeQuery("select distinct v.fundTransfer from VerificationRequest v where v.fundTransfer.creator.corporateHouse=:corporateHouse and v.verified = false and v.fundTransfer.status ='QUEUED' and v.approverGroup in (:approverGroupList)", [corporateHouse:corporateHouse],[approverGroupList:approverGroupList])
```

However I am getting the following exception :

```
/fund-transfer/list-verification-requests
Class
    org.hibernate.QueryException
Message
    Not all named parameters have been set: [approverGroupList] [select distinct v.fundTransfer from VerificationRequest v where v.fundTransfer.creator.corporateHouse=:corporateHouse and v.verified = false and v.fundTransfer.status ='QUEUED' and v.approverGroup in (:approverGroupList)]
```

Also corporateHouse is an object that's passes to the method executing this query and its not null.
What could be the reason?

P.S. I am new to grails!

Comment: Let me guess: No all parameters have been set?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You've passed two maps to `executeQuery`:

```
VerificationRequest.executeQuery("...", [corporateHouse:corporateHouse],[approverGroupList:approverGroupList])
```

It should be one map with two values:

```
VerificationRequest.executeQuery("...", [corporateHouse:corporateHouse, approverGroupList:approverGroupList])
```

According to [documentation](http://grails.org/doc/2.1.0/ref/Domain%20Classes/executeQuery.html) the second map was taken as map with additional parameters.

Answer (score 4):

[Looks like](http://grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Domain%20Classes/executeQuery.html) the parameters should be in *one* map, like this:

```
[corporateHouse:corporateHouse, approverGroupList:approverGroupList]
```

Answer (score 0):

It means that you have not set all the parameters in the query. You have missed some check your query execution code

Comment: Can you point out where ? I see no error to be honest! But ofcourse I am totally new to grails!